# ui-router multiple named nested views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-bootstrap

I have a nested view like this

```
<div ui-view="master" id="ng-view">
  <div class="container-fluid height-full">
      <div ui-view="globalNavigationPanel" class="row"></div> 
     <div ui-view="detail" id="detailContent" class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my resolver

```
function resolveShell()
{
   return {
            'views': {
                'master': {
                    templateUrl: 'core/views/shell.html',
                    controller: 'core/controllers/shellcontroller.js',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                },
                'globalNavigationPanel': {
                    templateUrl: 'core/views/globalNavigationPanel',
                    controller: 'core/controllers/globalNavigationPanelController.js',
                    controllerAs: 'gpvm',
                }
            },
            'resolve': {
                load: [
                    '$q', '$rootScope', ($q, $rootScope) => {
                        var dependencies = [
                            'core/controllers/shellcontroller.js',
                            'core/controllers/globalNavigationPanelController.js'
                        ];
                        return resolveDependencies($q, $rootScope, dependencies);
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
  }
```

when I set the state i could see all the files downloaded and `shellcontroller.js` getting called, but **not** the `globalNavigationPanelController`.

Also I cannot see the `globalNavigationPanel` view updating.

Can I basically set state and resolve **multiple named nested views**?

Comment: I've also tried  'globalNavigationPanel@': {
                    templateUrl: 'core/views/globalNavigationPanel',... with two resolve one for each view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because we use multi views, which are nested in one state. That means, that we have to use absolute naming.

This way, we can instruct UI-Router, that the second view, should be placed into current state other view. It is not obvious what is the name of your state, but let's imagine that it would be 'shell'

```
'views': {
    'master': {
        ...
    },
    'globalNavigationPanel@shell': {
        ....
    }
},
```

Now, the template of our **`'shell'`** state should be *(I mean the **`templateUrl: 'core/views/shell.html',`**)*

```
<div class="container-fluid height-full">
   <div ui-view="globalNavigationPanel" class="row"></div> 
   <div ui-view="detail" id="detailContent" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

And the **`index.html`** should contain just:

```
<div ui-view="master" id="ng-view">
</div>
```

Because the master will contain a placeholder for the 'globalNavigationPanel'

Also check the doc

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of `viewname@statename`, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. `contact.item`. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.
>
> For example, the previous example could also be written as:

```
.state('report',{
    views: {
      'filters@': { },
      'tabledata@': { },
      'graph@': { }
    }
})
```

> Notice that the view names are now specified as absolute names, as opposed to the relative name. It is targeting the `'filters'`, `'tabledata'`, and `'graph'` views located in the root unnamed template. Since it's unnamed, there is nothing following the `'@'`. The root unnamed template is your index.html.

EXTEND - There **[is a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/zEmY9YkAnFfRltEULfEK?p=preview)**

This is the state definition:

```
  .state('shell', {
    url: '/shell',
    views: {
      'master' : {
        templateUrl: 'core/views/shell.html',
            controller: 'shellcontroller',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
      },
      'globalNavigationPanel@shell': {
        templateUrl: 'core/views/globalNavigationPanel.html',
            controller: 'globalNavigationPanelController',
            controllerAs: 'gpvm',
      }
    }
  })
```

These are the views

The **`templateUrl: 'core/views/shell.html',`**

```
<h2>shell</h2>

<p>{{text}}</p>

<hr />

<div class="container-fluid height-full">
   <div ui-view="globalNavigationPanel" class="row"></div> 
   <div ui-view="detail" id="detailContent" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

The **`templateUrl: 'core/views/globalNavigationPanel.html',`**

```
<h3>globalNavigationPanel</h3>

<p>{{text}}</p>
```

while index contains just:

```
<div ui-view="master" id="ng-view"></div>
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zEmY9YkAnFfRltEULfEK?p=preview)

Comment: I added  'globalNavigationPanel@shell': it is still not working :( . Could it be   because i am using angular bootstrap and registering the controller with the module only it is resolved?

app.etrading.register.controller('globalNavigationPanelController', GlobalNavigationPanelController);

Comment: yes i split the view in index.html. also the code flow goes into shellcontroller but not into globalnavigationpanel controller when debugging

Comment: i am inside office network with no plunker and jsfiddle.

Comment: I do have a plunker for you ;) check my updated answer. Hope this helps

Comment: Does it help? or are you still not able to make it?

Comment: no. I don't have plunker. Will have to go home and see. But i have followed what you have mentioned in here. Currently still not working. could be i am using angular bootstrap and registering the controller dynamically. but need to see

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. Probably because i am loading the controllers dynamically by resolving the controller itself and registering it with angular. I am now calling the calling the states separately.

Comment: i now have another problem, Once setting the states for master and globalNavigationPanel.  I set the state for details. Now this remove the html from globalNavigationPanel. any idea why this happens. may be this might hold the clue for the previous question as well.

Comment: It's a shame, that my detailed answer, with clear and working example (even you don't have own plunker) has no value...

Comment: it works. I am sorry. it did work after clearing the browser cache.

Comment: That's really awesome! Enjoy ui-router :)

Comment: How about if we want a template and controller on "shell" also? I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: @JDSmith I would suggest create new Question and maybe link this... Not only you could provide more details about the issue (and mostly add a link to broken plunker) - but you will also get larger audience attention... I'd say ;)